# NuxtLink and Vue router duplicate routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

**I use nuxt 3**

I have a navigation bar, it has `NuxtLink` with the attribute `:to`.

Links have a dynamic route `category/${slug}/`

The problem is that the `:to` attribute does not overwrite the current navigation, but adds it to the end of the current one, like that `category/${slug}/category/${slug}/`

If I use the usual `to` attribute, then everything is fine.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove last "/".

```js
`category/${slug}` // OK
`category/${slug}/` // Not OK
`/category/${slug}` // OK
```